# Calling function after import

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ccxt

Trying to adapt someone else's code example to my project and a bit confused on how to call a function after importing the file.

Console os logging error `Uncaught TypeError: loadData.markets is not a function`

I'm attempting to call the `markets()` function from this file after importing:

```
/* eslint-disable */
var ccxt = require('ccxt')

export default {

  markets: async function () {

      var exchanges = {
          "bittrex": {},
          "bitfinex": {},
      }

      let ids = ccxt.exchanges.filter (id => id in exchanges)

      await Promise.all (ids.map (async id => {

        //  console.log (exchanges[id])

          // // instantiate the exchange
          let exchange = new ccxt[id] (exchanges[id])
        //  console.log (exchange.id, exchange.apiKey)
          exchanges[id] = exchange

          // load markets
          var markets = await exchange.loadMarkets ()
          console.log (exchange.id, 'loaded')
          exchanges[exchange.id].markets = markets

          return exchange
      }))

      // when all of them are ready, do your other things
      console.log ('Loaded exchanges:', ids.join (', '))
      return exchanges
      //console.log(exchanges.bitfinex.markets)
  }

}
```

Here is the mixin:

loadDataMixin.js

```
/* eslint-disable */
const ccxt = require('ccxt')
const loadData = require('../../lib/loadData')

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      exchangeList: ccxt.exchanges,
      markets: {}
    }
  },
  methods: {
    listExchanges() {
      console.log(this.exchangeList)
    },
    loadMarkets() {
      this.markets = loadData.markets()
    }
  }
}
```

This is the component:

```
<template>
  <div id="app" class="container">
    <div>
      <h1>Arb Bot</h1>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="loadMarkets()">Load data</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</template>

<script>
  /* eslint-disable */

  import loadDataMixin from './components/mixins/loadDataMixin'
  const ccxt = require('ccxt')

  export default {
    name: 'App',
    mixins: [loadDataMixin]
  }
</script>

<style>
  #app {
    font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    color: #2c3e50;
    margin-top: 60px;
  }

  .main-table {
    margin-top: 20px;
  }
</style>
```

How can I call the markets() function from loadData.js?

Comment: Probably need to use: `const loadData = require('../../lib/loadData').default` instead or `import loadData from '../../lib/loadData'`